# How to fake migrations for not to create a specific existing intermediary table

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

I have following models

```
class VucutBolgesi(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    bolge = models.CharField(verbose_name="Bölge", max_length=75)
    hareketler = models.ManyToManyField("Hareket", verbose_name="Hareketler", null=True, blank=True, help_text="Bölgeyi çalıştıran hareketler")


class Hareket(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    hareket = models.CharField(verbose_name="Hareket", max_length=75 )
    bolgeler = models.ManyToManyField(VucutBolgesi, verbose_name="Çalıştırdığı Bölgeler", null=True, blank=True,
                                      help_text="Hareketin çalıştırdığı bölgeler")
```

I have the same M2M on both table since I wish to display same intermediate table on both admin forms. They also have to use the same table (not create two separate tables) since one change in one admin form must be reflected to the other. Like, If I add a new `Hareket` to `VucutBolgesi` through `HareketAdmin` then the same result shoudl be visible on `VucutBolgesiAdmin` too.

For achieving this, I first remove `hareketler` M2M field from `VucutBolgesi` so `Hareketler` model would create the intermediate table. I migrate this and then add `hareketler` to `VucutBolgesi` with `db_table` attribute so it will recognize the same intermediary table.

final look of the field is as folows

```
hareketler = models.ManyToManyField("Hareket", verbose_name="Hareketler", db_table="antrenman_hareket_bolgeler",
                                    null=True, blank=True, help_text="Bölgeyi çalıştıran hareketler")
```

When I try to migrate this, django throw following exception

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "antrenman_hareket_bolgeler" already exists
```

How should I fake this migration?

Following is the migration django creates each time I run `makemigrations`

```
dependencies = [
    ('antrenman', '0005_vucutbolgesi_hareketler'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='vucutbolgesi',
        name='hareketler',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='antrenman.Hareket', db_table=b'antrenman_hareket_bolgeler', blank=True, help_text=b'B\xc3\xb6lgeyi \xc3\xa7al\xc4\xb1\xc5\x9ft\xc4\xb1ran hareketler', null=True, verbose_name=b'Hareketler'),
        preserve_default=True,
    ),
]
```

Note: Editing related migration file and removing `migrations.AddField` fo not work since django creates the same `migrations.AddField` with each `makemigrations`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it possible to make a migration always to be faked, just override the apply and unapply methods. The consequences of this are not sufficiently investigated, but this far it works for me.

In the following example we create a migration that reuses `django.contrib.auth.User.group`'s M2M table `b'profile_user_groups`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('profile', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='organizations',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(db_column=b'group_id', db_table=b'profile_user_groups', related_name='members', to='profile.Organization'),
        ),
    ]

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state.clone()

    def unapply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state.clone()
```

Comment: This is currently my favorite post on the entire of SO! A 5 year old post saved my life!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Solution was so simple.

You must be sure related migration is the only migration operation that needed to be faked. You must first create the migration with

```
python manage.py makemigrations antrenman
```

Then apply that migration with `--fake`

```
python manage.py migrate --fake antrenman
```

Handicap is, other developers should know that they have to **fake** related migration. If there are others migrations alongside with this one, they should make them first and then **fake** this one.

It is too bad there is no parameter that tells related migration should be real or fake.