# makemigrations does not create the trough model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have made changes to  one of my models in my project and migrate, makemigrations does not work as expected. Rebuilding the database creates only 2 out of 3 tables from my models.py and i cannot figure out the problem.

There are two different apps; "blog" and "users". both are registered in the setting.py.

I completely removed the database and deleted the migrations folders. 
then i tried the following stuff:

```
django makemigrations blog 
django migrate blog
```

doing a global `django makemigrations`  does not have any effect, no changes are detected.

here is the relevant models.py of "blog":

```
class Room(models.Model):
   roomname = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True)
   roomeditors=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='rooms_user_can_edit', blank=True)
   displayadmin=models.ForeignKey(User, 
   related_name='room_user_is_displayadmin',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.roomname



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room, related_name='roomposts', through='Display')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return "/post/{}/".format(self.pk)

class Display(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        auto_created = True
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isdisplayed = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.isdisplayed)
```

every table gets created except from display. the output is:

```
Migrations for 'blog':
  blog\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Room
    - Create model Post
```

Comment: Why do you write `auto_created = True` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394323/how-to-correctly-use-auto-created-attribute-in-django.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because posts can be written in multiple rooms, but for every post -> room connection i want a boolean value "isdisplayed". thats why i used a trough model.  i used ´´´ auto_created = True ´´´ is because i want the display objects to be auto-created when a new post is created. The code worked well as is should until i tried to recreate the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  when i comment out the ``` class meta: auto_created = True ``` and try to migrate, i get the following error: ``` ValueError: Cannot alter field blog.Post.rooms into blog.Post.rooms - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields) ````

Comment: @Tankard666: perhaps you should do this in two steps: first remove the m2m, then add a new one (the next migration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `auto_created = True` in your model's Meta class, which is not recommended neither its documented. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/) is the list of all possible meta options you can give inside your model.

Official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.auto_created) says:

> auto_created: Boolean flag that indicates if the field was automatically created, such as the OneToOneField used by model inheritance.

Giving this in Meta refrains Django to create this model itself.

Comment: i deleted the database again and made a new Migration, now everything works fine. Thank you very much!